# Local network p2p connection with Windows Store Apps

Tags: windows-runtime, winjs, multiplayer

I am building a small cards game for Windows Store using HTML/JS as my programming languages. One of the features that I would like to add is multiplayer capability. My game it's based on a 1 versus 1 player (unlike Hearts where you need 4 players), so an ad-hoc peer-to-peer connection is enough. Also, keep in mind that I am only considering local network multiplayer, without internet support (meaning that "privateNetworkClientServer" capability is required on that app manifest).

So I am imagining, when a player want to start a multiplayer game, the app will periodically broadcast a message to find any candidates. Meanwhile he will also have to listen for those same messages (in case of another player is broadcasting them also). When they find which other we transmit the game state back and forward to perform the required games changes.

My question is, does WinRT provide any functionality out of the box to do something like this? If no, do you have any suggestion for my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for the [PeerFinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.peerfinder.aspx) class.  Proximity can use either NFC or by browsing on the same subnet.  Note, in the case of WiFi, not all WiFI cards support the browsing model, so some older PCs may not be able to use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [proximity sample application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Proximity-Sample-88129731) on msdn should help you with this.

Comment: it looks like proximity API is focus on NFC (Near field communications). I will give it a try, but I seriously bout that will do the trick. Thanks anyway